# How to prevent keras from renaming layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

When I re-create a model, keras always makes a new name for a layer (conv2d_2 and so on) even if I override the model. How to make keras using the same name every time I run it without restarting the kernel.

Comment: In tensorflow 1.X, resetting the default graph via `tf.reset_default_graph()` may help. Alternatively, you could set the layer names yourself

Comment: Make each model within a new graph (e.g. within a `with tf.Graph().as_default():`) block or, if using the default graph, reset it with `tf.reset_default_graph()`.

Comment: What do you mean if you override the model?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro `model = ...` that I mean by override. Btw, could you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/58374010/12213054

Comment: @GPhilo I will accept your answer if you publish it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Tensorflow (1.X) as a backend, whenever you add a new layer to any model, the name of the layer -unless manually set- will be set to the default name for that layer, plus an incremental index at the end.

Defining a new model is not enough to reset the incrementing index, because all models end up on the **same** underlying graph. **To reset the index, you must reset the underlying graph.**

In TF 1.X, this is done via `tf.reset_default_graph()`. In TF 2.0, you can do this via the v1 compatibility API: `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()` (the latter will also solve some deprecation warnings you might get with the latest versions of TF 1.X)